# Convert last number in a cell to a letter in another cell using 2 arguments

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If the last character in a cell = “1” Then convert that character in a new cell to “A” and if the last character in a cell = “3” Then convert that character in a new cell to “C”.
i.e.
Cell A1 - MIARD01N01
Cell A2 - MIARD01N0A
And
Cell A1 - MIARD01N03
Cell A2 - MIARD01N0C

Thanks

I used the following formula for one case but i need to incorporate an If Then for the second argument.

```
=REPLACE(A1,10,1,A)
```

Comment: `=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)&CHAR(64+RIGHT(A1,1))`

Comment: Or, `=REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1),1,CHAR(64+RIGHT(A1)))`

Comment: These work but I need 2 if then arguments. If last char = "1" then "A" or if last char = "3" then "C"

Comment: Whoops! never mind That works!!! Thanks so much!

Comment: I see what you did. You made it so it converts that last char from number to alphanumeric equivalent which is useful;, but what If i wanted to convert a specific number to a specific letter. i.e 1= B and 3 = D?

Comment: To do so, you would just need to change the 64 to 65

Comment: Already mentioned above by @SpectralInstance ^^^

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, it works with your existing formula, just replace <kbd>10</kbd> & <kbd>A</kbd> with <kbd>LEN(A1)</kbd> & <kbd>CHAR(64+RIGHT(A1))</kbd>, that said the formula will be:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A2</kbd>

```
=REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1),1,CHAR(64+RIGHT(A1)))
```

---